# UITableViewCell Editing Minus Sign Frame?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview

I want to move the minus sign to the right. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible, but I'd start by looking into subclassing the `UITableViewCell` and overriding its `layoutSubviews` method.

But I don't believe you can, you only have access to the `contentView`, the `accessoryView`, the `backgroundView`, not the `deleteConfirmationView`. The closest thing you can find in [`UITableViewCell`'s reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the boolean `showingDeleteConfirmation`.

So you could try subclassing the `UITableViewCell`and adding your own delete confirmation button where you want, by responding to `willTransitionToState:` when the new state is `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask`.

Comment: Doesn't UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask only get called when the actual delete button show up? I am trying to change the button icons that show up on the left when you enter UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete mode.

Although I guess I could do soemthing like if(editing) and uitableviewcelleditingstyledelete then show custom buttons. Then add actions to those buttons and when the buttons are clicked use Core Animation to rotate the button 90 degrees, override the showingDeleteConfirmation property and update the property to say YES.

Comment: Ended up doing  something like this. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Could you share some code ? I need to achieve something like this.